# Best way to update an object with another object of the same type in .Net?

Tags: c#

Similar questions have been asked but cannot find a solution that works well. 
What I have is a rather large object (Viper object) that has several sub objects and Lists. I will receive a new instance of a Viper object several times a second and I need to merge that data into a "master" Viper object. If the property is null skip it if not replace it. Some properties that are lists will just be replaced by the new property, some list properties will just append the new list to the existing one.

Point being, there are properties that need some custom logic to determine how to perform the merge. The question is should I use something like AutoMapper/Value Injector or just write a custom Merge command in the data model that takes another Viper object? This needs to be as efficient as possible since it will be called a lot.

Here is the data model:

```
public class Viper
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int ViperId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int RecordCount { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Byte Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int CaseStage { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false,EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public CaseDetail CaseDetail { get; set; }

    private ViperMetaData _metaData;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public ViperMetaData MetaData {
        get { return _metaData; }
        set
        {
            _metaData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MetaData");
        }
    }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<CasePatientData> PatientDetailsTable1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<CasePatientData> PatientDetailsTable2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<CasePatientData> PatientDetailsTable3 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<CasePatientData> PatientDetailsTable4 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<CaseChannel> CaseChannelDataList { get; set; } // list of all channels available in a specific case/viper

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<EventsData> EventsDataList { get; set; }


    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<ChannelData> ChannelDataList { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public CasePatientDetails CasePatientDetails { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<CaseFluids> CaseFluidsList { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<PatientTable> PatientTableNames { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? TimeOffset { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false,EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Html { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<CaseDocument> CaseDocuments { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<Gauge> Gauges { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<BloodGasData> BloodGasDataList { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<CardioplegiaData> CardioplegiaDataList { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<ComplianceDataUnit> ComplianceDataList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Auto Mapper or Value Injector as you mentioned. Especially if your property names are similiar across objects, you barely need to write any code. For the custom mappings, it is very easy to write custom functions to pass to the mapping method. Very useful. Quick psuedo code of what that would look like:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Viper, ViperDto>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Property, opt => opt.NullSubstitute("N/A"));
var merged = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(viper, viperDTO);
```

Comment: My initial test with AutoMapper (never used this before so very green) copied the nulls over as well so it appears I will have to have a custom handler for every property even if I have to say don't copy if null. If that is the case it does not seem to be any less code than if I were to write a custom function. Does that sound right or have I missed something in AutoMapper? Also I am merging 2 Viper objects so all properties are identical except some will be null in the "incoming" object.

Comment: Automapper contains a NullSubstitution method. It is clean and concise. See this page for an example: http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/2011/03/07/automapper-mapping-objects-part-1-of-7-nullsubsitution/

Comment: I must be missing something with AutoMapper. If I have to add a NullSubstitution entry for every property in the object why is that easier than just creating a MergeWith function in the data model itself? Also, since I am using the object with data binding I can't just replace it I really need to modify the original. Is AutoMapper still possible and easier than custom MergeWith functions in the Viper object and all sub objects?

Comment: It is probably a wash. If ALL members require custom code, no library will help you. You might as well write it from scratch. If there are members that don't require custom code and can just map on their own, this is where AutoMapper/ValueInjector are most useful as you only specify the one CreateMap call.